# Camel - File Reading 10 lines batch

Tags: apache-camel

We are trying to read a very large CSV file(which cannot be fully loaded to memory) in batches say 100 lines per batch) using Apache Camel.   Any assistance that can be provided will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use the splitter EIP in streaming mode: http://camel.apache.org/splitter
And read the link and see the section about grouping N lines together. This allows you to read and process the files with 100 lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [throttler](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html) to throttle the number files loaded at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` with groups, e.g.:
`from(CSV).split().tokenize("\n", 100).streaming()`
where each `Exchange` body will be a `String` containing a group of 100 lines.